# How does C++ checks an array's size when passed by reference

Tags: c++, arrays, memory

When passing an array by reference to a function like for instance:

```
void Foo(double (&MyList)[3]);
```

The code wont compile when you try to pass an array of size different of 3 to this function.
From what i have been able to understand in c++, there is no way to know the size of an array once it is instantiated.

How is the compiler able to keep track of the size of an array?
And why then, if it is able to check the size of arrays, such code would still compile?

```
int MyTab[3]
MyTab[3] = 5;
```

Comment: It doesn’t. That’s why it’s so easy to corrupt memory in C and C++.

Comment: All these issues can be remedied by using `std::vector`.  The `std::vector` has a `size` member function.  The `std::vector` can be passed by reference, and the operator `[]` can be used.

Comment: *How is the compiler able to keep track of the size of an array?*  In this case, you told the compiler the size of the array - just like every other case where you have to use the actual size of the array.  Either the actual array is in scope or you somehow told the compiler how big it is.

Comment: If you want better information, then one option is to use compile-time measures (i.e. templates) to expand the array size into an additional function parameter specifying the size.

Comment: @Dai: The compiler does indeed track arrays sizes.... usually

Comment: @MooingDuck Right - but as soon as you cross a function boundary and the array-type decays to a pointer type then you're stuck :) But (according to my recollection of the ISO spec) the compiler is not required to issue an error when it knows an out-of-bound index will be used (e.g. when using a `constexpr` index) nor is it required to add runtime bounds checks - or infer the bounds of the index from flow-analysis (I know _some_ compilers support this but they'll only issue warnings).

Comment: @Dai: Except... "When passing an array by reference to a function like for instance: `void Foo(double (&MyList)[3]);`", which this question is about. In this case, it does _not_ decay to a pointer type, because you're passing a reference, _not an array_. This results in a hard compiler error in all compilers if the wrong size is passed.

Comment: @Dai the compiler does know the size. `int[3]` is a different type than eg `int[4]` arrays are not pointers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ can only track the size of arrays with automatic or static storage duration (i.e. local or global variables) because that's the only place where fixed sized arrays can exist (and thus variables of array type can only reference those). The confusing part is that arrays are allowed to decay to pointers which can happen very quickly (e.g. if you pass the array as a function argument without the parameter beeing a **reference** to an array).

```
void foo(int i[]);  // i will be a pointer, not an array

template <std::size_t N>
void foo(int (&i)[N]);   // i is a reference to an array with size N
```

Arrays with dynamic storage duration (i.e. arrays created with `new`) cannot be referenced by an array type, because such an array must have a compile time known size and `new` can create dynamic arrays (the size is possibly only known at runtime).   Because of that, `new` gives you a pointer to the first element of the array and at that point the compiler isn't able to help you anymore.

```
int i[] = new int[10];  // i is not an array, it's a pointer
int i[10];              // i is an array, the array is located on the stack
```

Regarding your

```
int MyTab[3];
MyTab[3] = 5;
```

example, lets quote [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator):

> The built-in subscript expression E1[E2] is exactly identical to the
>   expression *(E1 + E2)

Translated to your case:

`MyTab[3]` is identical to `*(MyTab + 3)` and here comes our lovely pointer decay again. The `operator+` operates on a pointer and an integral and so `MyTab` decays to a pointer again, losing all its size information.

Besides that, you could still get the end iterator by the out of bound access (you're just not allowed to read or write the value):

```
int* begin = MyTab;   // pointer decay again, equal to &MyTab[0]
int* end = &MyTab[3]; // get a pointer to one past the end (aka end iterator)
```

The compiler could indeed warn you for larger out of bounds accesses tho, not sure why its not doing that.

Comment: "C++ can only track the size of arrays that are located on the stack because that's the only place where variables of an array type can exist."  - what about `calloc( 123, sizeof(char) )` ?

Comment: @Dai: Even in that case, C++ doesn't track the size.  The Free Store itself does.

Comment: A workaround is use `std:array` For instance `auto *parray = new std::array<char,10>` It takes up the same amount of storage but now the compiler knows how many elements it has. But in most cases `std::vector` is better.